# java not finding class in jar after successfully compiling with javac against same jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, caliper

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222991/why-is-hashcode-slower-than-a-similar-method/24416940#24416940) on stackoverflow and thought I'd try to run the benchmark myself. I downloaded [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) and compiled it successfully using maven. I then compiled [HashCodeBenchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/HashCodeBenchmark.java) from the linked question successfully using the jar that maven created. However, when I try to run HashCodeBenchmark, java complains that it cannot find a entrypoint class inside the jar.

I am utterly perplexed and have no idea what the problem is.

compile:

```
$ javac benchmark/HashCodeBenchmark.java \
    -classpath caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar \
    && echo success
success
```

run:

```
$ java benchmark.HashCodeBenchmark -classpath caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/caliper/runner/CaliperMain
    at benchmark.HashCodeBenchmark.main(HashCodeBenchmark.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're providing the `-classpath` argument *after* the class name - so it's just being passed to your `main` method. You need to provide it *before* the class name, and include the current directory in the classpath too:

```
$ java -classpath caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar:. benchmark.HashCodeBenchmark
```

Comment: Thank you, it's been a while since I used java, let alone on the command line. I'd forgotten that args after the class are passed args to the main method.