# Apache Commons Lang3 Hashcode, Equals and ToString including Enums

Tags: java, enums, equals, hashcode, apache-commons-lang3

We have few datatypes defined for our service response and request objects in a model. Recently we found a need of implementing *ToString, HashCode and Equals* on all such types to make use of these over comparison and assertions. Confirming from few source like [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609), [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract?noredirect=1&lq=1)  etc we followed implementing toString, equals and hashcode using `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder`, `HashCodeBuilder` and `ToStringBuilder` as follows -

---

***Response.java***

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class Response {

    private Integer value;
    private Currency currency;
    private Object edited;

    public Response() {
    }

    public Response(Integer value, Currency currency, Object edited) {
        this.value = value;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.edited = edited;
    }

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getEdited() {
        return edited;
    }

    public void setEdited(Object edited) {
        this.edited = edited;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Response Response = (Response) o;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(value, Response.value).append(currency, Response.currency)
                                  .append(edited, Response.edited).isEquals();
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).append(value).append(currency).append(edited).toHashCode();
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Response{" + "value=" + value + ", currency=" + currency + ", edited=" + edited + '}';
    }
}
```

***Currency.java***

```
public enum Currency {
    INR
}
```

---

On implementing these using the default library version, there is a [thought around enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885095/what-is-the-reason-behind-enum-hashcode) that comes to our mind -

Is it correct to use the default hashcode and equals from the library when a datatype might contain parameters including enums as well?
Is there a library(within commons would be great) support to implementing a correct optimized solution to overriding implementation of hashcode and equals?

On a side note does the library implementation needs an improvement here or is it correct to what exists?

---

***Edit***: Have added the implementation over an `Object` field(`edited`) in the class as well. The concern there being same if I override the hashCode and equals implementation for these as well.

Do I end up using an Object's hashcode which is different for different instances as it is mostly the memory mapped address?

***Edit 2***: I can also see a concern raised on the inconsistent implementation on HashCode for Enum values on [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-780)

Comment: Enums have a default, perfectly correct implementation of hashCode and equals.

Comment: @LouisWasserman does that mean I can rely on the current implementation? any thoughts over comparing two objects of `Response` type generated using different JVMs?

Comment: A) yes B) you can only call `equals` from inside a single JVM.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you. Can you provide any source for in-depth understanding of `B` above.

Comment: You are calling .equals.  .equals is being called in one Java runtime.  That's the one.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - got your point, apologies but have updated the question with a concern over Object fields here as well.

Comment: @nullpointer. I think that is a non issue. See the resolution notes they have marked it as "Won't Fix ". This JIRA was opened in Dec 2011 and close recently in Oct 2016. I do not think this will be an issue as well. It seems they had added a patch in 2014, so logically speaking this shouldnt be a concern.

Comment: Reading it further I noticed this was not opened as bug a a new feature. Hence using HashCodeBuilder the way you are using should be fine

Comment: @Acewin The use case we are aware of is as and when generation of different hashCode values for enum arises when a serialisation and deserialisation of response objects occurs on two different machines.

Comment: @nullpointer you shouldn't have any code dependent on the value of the hashcode (i.e. don't include that in your serialization), other than in building a hashcode encompassing contained objects.  The only requirement you can and should depend on is that the value remains consistent within an instance of the JVM runtime.

Comment: Which is not the case in the code example. You should only use fields in hashcode/equals that are effectively final. If you use your object as a key in a HashMap, and change the fields, the object may no longer hash to the same bucket.