# Do we have to override equals/hashcode for enums which are put in a hashmap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have a enum class as follows.

```
public enum Item {
   COKE("Coke", 25), PEPSI("Pepsi", 35), SODA("Soda", 45);
   private String name;
   private int price;

private Item(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getPrice() {
    return price;
}
}
```

and a hashmap defined as follows

```
private Map<Item, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
```

Do i need to override hashcode and equals in the enum `Item` class for `inventory.put()` and `inventory.get()` to work properly? If not, why?

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885095/what-is-the-reason-behind-enum-hashcode ?

Comment: Or have you ended up with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028231/apache-commons-lang3-hashcode-equals-and-tostring-including-enums?

Comment: Also check `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 13):

No, you don't. Why? Because reasonable implementations of these methods are already provided.

And even if you wanted to, you couldn't, as these methods are `final` in enums.

But also, don't use `HashMap` with an enum key type: use `EnumMap`, which is specialised for enum keys, and doesn't use `hashCode` or `equals` (it actually uses `ordinal`).

---

Edit: after reading [What is the reason behind Enum.hashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4885095/3788176), I note that the implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` are actually those from `Object`. But these *are* reasonable, because of the non-instantiability of enum values.

If you can't create a new instance of an enum value, there is no problem with using those defaults:

- An enum value must have the same hash code value as itself (and it doesn't matter what that value is);
- An enum value must be equal to itself, and not to any other, i.e. equality by identity.

Comment: But if Item was a class then we must override hashcode and equals in order for them to work in a Map. So What difference changing it to an enum makes?

Comment: All enums are subclasses of `Enum`. This class provides final implementations of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#hashCode())

Answer (score 0):

This post is from a while ago, but I think it's worth adding something about enum hashCode() that tripped me up...

The hashCode of an enum is fixed when the program starts up as an enum is essentially just a static object, so it Object.hashCode() will return the same value for the duration of the running program.

However, the next time the program runs, this is quite likely not the same address in memory.

enums are compared (with equals) by their address in memory (==) not by equals(). This is why hashCode() has to do the same, or as the documentation says "something similar" (more or less).

If you have some other class that contains your enum, and you auto-generate a hashCode for it from your IDE, then the hash code of that new class will depend on the time you run the code.

If this other class is persisted, its hash code will not be equal across program start ups. (My problem arose from converting the hashCode into a hex string and using it as a hash key for indexing objects... Doh!). I got round it by taking the string of the enum in the other class, and hashing that. Messy.

The hashCode method of an enum is final, so you can't override it.